# Subtracting rows between data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

```
df1
Name   | std
kumar  | 8
Ravi   | 10
Sri    | 2
Ram    | 4


df2,
Name   | std
Sri    | 2
Ram    | 4
```

I want to subtract df2 rows from df1 and I tried,

```
df1.subtract(df2,fill_value=None)
```

but I am getting error,

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

My desired output,

```
df3
Name   | std
kumar  | 8
Ravi   | 10
```

Comment: It is not clear what the column names are in your 'dataframe'.  The method `subtract` will align the dataframe on matching indices and columns (even the index names need to be identical).  Try to paste the output of `df.iloc[:5, :5]` so that we can get a better idea what your data looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `indicator` and outer join, [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering and then remove helper column with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

DataFrames are joined on all columns, so `on` parameter can be omit.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['kumar','Ravi','Sri','Ram'],
                    'std':[8,10,2,4],
                    'col':list('abcd')})
print (df1)
    Name col  std
0  kumar   a    8
1   Ravi   b   10
2    Sri   c    2
3    Ram   d    4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Sri','Ram'],
                    'std':[2,4],
                    'col':list('cd')})
print (df2)
  Name col  std
0  Sri   c    2
1  Ram   d    4

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
        .query('_merge=="left_only"')
        .drop('_merge',1)
print (df3)
    Name col  std
0  kumar   a    8
1   Ravi   b   10
```

Comment: there is more columns with strings?

Comment: your edited version gives, only the names column, I want all the columns. I have 6 string columns in my actual dataframe

Comment: I edited my question, can you pls check my desired output

Comment: What is output if in second `df2` is `Ram    | 3` ?

Comment: same as my desired output

Comment: I am trying to remove the rows which are present in both df1 and df2

Comment: only by column `Name` ? Or by all columns?

Comment: I completely rewrite answer, please check it.

Comment: @pyd - There is difference between my and piRSquared answer - if need check only column `Name`, beter is `pir` answer, but if need check all columns, need my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45522478/how-to-remove-entire-column-if-a-particular-row-has-duplicate-values-in-a-datafr

Answer (score 9):

Use [**`pd.Series.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
df1[~df1.Name.isin(df2.Name)]

    Name  std
0  kumar    8
1   Ravi   10
```

Comment: Any possible issues with this approach?

Comment: No.  This is a solid approach.

Answer (score 0):

You "numbers" are not numbers but strings. Make them numbers first. If only some columns are numeric, select them before conversion:

```
numeric = ["c1", "c2", "c3", ...] # All numeric columns
df1.set_index('Name')[numeric].astype(int) \
- df2.set_index('Name')[numeric].astype(int)
```

Comment: we can change, but I have some more string columns

Comment: Then you have to select numeric columns before subtraction. See updated answer.