# how to remove entire column if a particular row has duplicate values in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this,

```
 df,

        Name    City
   0    sri     chennai
   1    pedhci  pune
   2    bahra   pune
```

there is a duplicate in City column.

I tried:

```
df["City"].drop_duplicates()
```

but it gives only the particular column.

my desired output should be

```
output_df
        Name    City
   0    sri     chennai
   1    pedhci  pune
```

Comment: Is there a case where row 1 might have gotten deleted, instead of row 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset='City')
```

if you want to store the result in a new dataframe, or:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='City',inplace=True)
```

if you want to update `df`.

This produces:

```
>>> df
      City    Name
0  chennai     sri
1     pune  pedhci
2     pune   bahra
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset='City')
      City    Name
0  chennai     sri
1     pune  pedhci
```

This will thus only take duplicates for `City` into account, duplicates in `Name` are ignored.